# RestSharp usando certificado ssl

Tags: rest, ssl

Preciso usar certificado para conectar a um servidor `https` com `restsharp`. Estou usando este código:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
client.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCertificado());

var request = new RestRequest("authorisationTransaction", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
```

Mas recebo a mensagem:

> A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Não foi possível estabelecer
>   relação de confiança para o canal seguro de SSL/TLS.

Para ler o certificado do disco estou usando este método:

```
    private X509Certificate GetCertificado()
    {
        string Certificate = "certificado.cer";
        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate();
        cert.Import(Certificate);
        return cert;
    }
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso ?
Obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, esse erro pode ter um milhão de causas, não necessariamente relacionada a algo de errado no seu código. Não tenho uma resposta pra te dar, mas sugiro [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/703272/520779) e [essa outra](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15377075/520779) no SOen como pontos de partida.

Answer (score -3):

Após o seu request coloque isso:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Irá ficar assim:

```
var request = new RestRequest("authorisationTransaction", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
**ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;**
```